# case match a `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

In Java we can do `switch(value) {case(x): // do something;}`

In Scala, we can do something similar with case match expressions:

```
val a = 1
a match {
  case 1 => 1
  case 2 => 2
} // 1
```

However, it doesn't work with a value of type `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`.

```
val tpe = typeOf[Int]
tpe match {
  case typeOf[Int] => 1
  case typeOf[Option[Any]] => 2
}
error: not found: type typeOf
case typeOf[Int] => 1
            ^
```

Instead, I have to do this:

```
if (tpe =:= typeOf[Int]) {...}
else if (tpe =:= Option[Any]) {...}
```

Is there a chance to use case match expression here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (although I'm not sure why you'd want to):

```
val tpe = typeOf[Int]

val intType = typeOf[Int]
val optionAnyType = typeOf[Option[Any]]

tpe match {
    case `intType` => 1
    case `optionAnyType` => 2
} //1
```

Comment: What if I want to "range match"? e.g.,

```if (tpe <:< typeOf[Seq[Any]]) {...} else if (tpe <:< Option[Any]) {...} else {...}```

Comment: @YikSanChan Then you'd need to do this: `tpe match { case i if i <:< typeOf[Seq[Any]] => ...; case j if j <:< typeOf[Option[Any]] => ...; case _ => ... }`